QMediaPlayer doesn't produce audio, but seems like it is trying. (No error messages)
I have already tried the solutions for other threads, and to no avail, so I am asking this question. At first I tried an OGG file, and then an MP3 file, but QMediaPlayer doesn't produce audio either way. However, my headphones do make a popping noise. I am new to Qt, so I'm sure it's somehow my code, but I need help figuring out what it is.
Current Code:
main.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>

QString readTextFile(QString path)
{
    QFile file(path);

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream in(&file);
        return in.readAll();
    }

    return "";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString styles = readTextFile(":/Resources/styles.css");

    if(styles.length() > 0)
    {
        a.setStyleSheet(styles);
    }

    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowTitle("Sudoku Solver");

    w.show();

    QMediaPlayer * p = new QMediaPlayer;
    QAudioOutput * d = new QAudioOutput;

    p->setAudioOutput(d);
    p->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo(":/Resources/Resources/S012_LvUp.mp3").absoluteFilePath()));
    d->setVolume(0.02);

    qDebug() <<"I see this";

    p->play();

    return a.exec();

}

.pro file:
QT       += core gui

QT       += core multimedia

TARGET = MediaPlayer

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    Resources.qrc


Other things I have tried:

I initially had the QMediaPlayer code in a MouseRelease event, but I was concerned that it was being cut short once the event ended. Nothing changes either way.
In main.cpp, I have also tried the syntax:
p->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/Resources/Resources/S012_LvUp.mp3"));
I have tried volume levels from 0.02 to 1, but nothing changes.
My audio has been loaded as a Resource, so that isn't an issue.
In main.cpp, there is a line:
qDebug() <<"I see this";
just before the play() function. This qDebug line behaves as expected, both as a MouseRelease event and as above in main.cpp

Would appreciate any suggestions!

Using fromLocalFile() with a Qt resource makes absolutely no sense, since they obviously are not local files. Use QUrl("qrc:/<path")

@misucamante I see what you mean. With it being loaded as a resource, the address is considered different than if you were pulling it from the disk. That worked perfectly, thank you! Can you submit as an answer instead of a comment, so I can mark it as the answer?

There's no need for it, as similar questions and proper answers already exist, and we prefer to avoid duplicates: Using a resource file in QMediaPlayer. Please accept the duplicate proposal.

Note that putting the media player code in the mouse event handler would have been a poor choice. Luckily, you chose to avoid it, but not for the proper reason, though, as events do not "end": if you created it without any parent (as you currently do) or persistent reference, it would've been destroyed as soon as the handler function returned; if you created it with a parent, that would've been a huge memory leak, as every new mouse event would've created a new mediaplayer without destroying any existing one (unless you properly managed its deletion upon playback ending). And this without »

» even counting the issue of creating a new media player and audio output within an user input event handler, which, even more than other functions eventually called in the UI thread, should always return as soon as possible without unnecessary overhead. At the very least, the media player should've been created just once (possibly in the constructor) and eventually [re]starting the playback in the mouse event handler (possibly with the file already loaded). Note that for short sounds that need to be played "quickly" (which is the case of mouse events), you should consider using alternatives »

» such as QSound (if you're still on Qt5) or QSoundEffect. They require using uncompressed audio files, but if they're short enough they shouldn't impact too much the qrc size and memory usage, and they will work better (and faster) than using QMediaPlayer.

I have seen a little about QSoundEffect, so I can look into that. The original file is OGG, so that's why I was using QMediaPlayer. Based on your suggestion, I have been trying to use it (as-is, since the audio is playing) by setting everything up in the constructor, passing the QMediaPlayer into the event, and playing it from there. I overloaded the mouseReleaseEvent in both the cpp file and header file, and I have no errors, but the audio isn't playing. It should play when you click the app background (MainWindow), so I shouldn't need to connect() anything, right?

Also, to be more explicit with what I'm doing, I have the QMediaPlayer  * p and QAudioOutput * d declared in the constructor, I have setAudioOutput, setSource, and setVolume all in the constructor as well. Then (in theory), I would be passing *p to the mouseReleaseEvent anytime the user clicks the background/empty space of the app. in the event, then, I have p->play(). However, no audio is playing. Is there anything special that needs to be done when overloading events?

You don't pass things to an event handler, Qt passes the event, nothing else. If things have been properly done, doing p->play() there should work anywhere (assuming the handler has been triggered to begin with, obviously), but without seeing your code I really can't tell you what prevented that in your case.

I'll just make a new question, since I can't post code, pictures, or create a chat.

Never mind, it seems  I'm incredibly dumb. I declared my QMediaPlayer in the MainWindow constructor as if it was a new object, rather than a part of the MainWindow itself. Everything works now. Thank you for all your help!
